# If statement in JSon

Tags: json, if-statement

I work a no-code app maker called Adalo. I am connected my app to a API that sends emails automatically. But in order for me to connect to the API, I must first "Run Test Request" which tries to send a request to the API. If I put an email into the "to" instead of "User Email" it will work perfectly. However, I currently have it set as a variable which is populated by data records. When I try to "Run Test Request", it does not work, because it does not no where to pull the data from during the test (it knows where to get the data outside the test). So what happens is the "To" email becomes "" which it says is an invalid email, so the test cannot pass. I am trying to think of a work around, because I know the code works, its just that the test wont let it work with a variable. So I wanted to know if I could some how create an if statement that said something like

```
if User Email == ""
     then User Email = "g@gmail.com"
```

The syntax is wrong, but hopefully you understand what I am getting at.

Below is the current code I have. This has to be in JSON, my understand is that I cannot insert Java.

```
{
    "sender": {
        "name": "Peculiar Yogi Mail", 
        "email": "namaste@peculiaryogi.com" 
    },
    "to": [{
        "email": "USER EMAIL", 
        "name": "USER FIRST NAME" 
    }],
    "subject": "Peculiar Yogi Class Booking Confirmation",
"htmlContent":"<html><head></head><body><p>Hello,</p><p>This is to confirm that you've successfully booked a class at Peculiar Yogi.</p><p>Class Name:</p><p>Class Instructor</p><p>Class Time:</p><p>Namaste.</p></body></html>"
}
```

Comment: Mock the API response for your test case?

Comment: I am using SendInBlue api. Are you saying I could just tell SendInBlue to accept it?

Comment: JSON has no concept of a conditional statement. It is not a programming language, just a data type. You should investigate using other methods to do what you need, like using conditional statements in the host program to change how the JSON object is created/populated.